# Content Assist Not Working in Nodeclipse

Tags: eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse

I'm using Eclipse Luna with Nodeclipse 0.17 with Node.js v0.10.32

```
var temp = ["a","b"];
temp.
```

I'm not getting code assist after the period or after hitting CTRL-SPACE

Answer (score 0):

That is just array and is not Node.js specific.

[image: ab]

Raise issue at https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/
and specify what other modules you are using.

Recommended Nodeclipse install is getting Enide Studio plugin set.

read http://www.nodeclipse.org ->   Download

[image: installing]